# NFS : restrict kerberos authentication to some user accounts

Tags: linux, nfs, kerberos

I'm trying to grant access to a single freeipa user to an nfs share (if possible the machine account).
My etc exports looks like :

```
/data lemp1.domain.local(rw,sync,sec=krb5p)
```

And my working mount is :

```
mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p nfs1.domain.local:/data /data
```

Now I can mount the directory, I'm trying to be more restrictive, and allow only some kerberos accounts to authenticate, is there a way to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Fix the ownership and permissions of the exported files.

Comment: Thanks. However what I'm trying to accomplish is a machine-based kerberos authentication, and based on `ipa host-find --all`, hosts accounts doesn't have uid. Do they ?

Comment: You've already restricted it to a single machine. The ownership and permissions restrict which users can access the files. You have nothing left to do.